# Angular Material md-input-container does not add an asterisk * to required input fields

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Angular Material is not adding asterisks to required input fields and I'm not sure why.

The view model code looks like this:

```
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input ng-model="vm.job.title"
                           md-maxlength="250"
                           required>
                </md-input-container>
```

And it renders looking like this:

[image]

I'm expecting the asterisk to show but they don't.

Comment: Looks like some dependency file is not imported properly. Here is the code pen, just added the above code and is working fine... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOXWAQ

Comment: I'm using the bower version 1.0.9 whereas you're codepen is version 1.1.0.rc4. When I changed the codepen to the previous version it failed too which is interesting because the correct code is included int he scss file not the compiled CSS. I'll try upgrading and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I updated Angular Material to version 1.1.0-rc4 and now it works as expected.